# Two questions here, regarding opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

The Code:
I am attempting to construct a python script that takes the RGB values of an image, along with the contours width and height into a neural network to determine if the little rc car I have constructed should go forward or turn right.
Code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

class Pic_Capture:
    def __init__(self):
        # print("Fuck you")
        self.i = 0
    def Img_Mods(self, cam):
        self.ret, self.frame = cam.read()
        self.buf1 = cv2.flip(self.frame, 1)
        # self.buf2 = cv2.cvtColor(self.buf1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.buf3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.buf1,(5,5),0)
        cv2.imshow('buf2', self.buf3)

    def Measurement_Bullshit(self):
        self.buf4 = cv2.cvtColor(self.buf3, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        self.buf5 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(self.buf4,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
        _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(self.buf5, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        for cnt in contours:
            M = cv2.moments(cnt)
            self.cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            self.cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
            print(self.cx, self.cy)
        cv2.imshow('buf4', self.buf4)

running = True
i = 0
Camera = Pic_Capture()

while running:
    Camera.Img_Mods(cam)

    if i % 30 == 0 and i != 0:
        Camera.Off_and_On_Again()
        Camera.Measurement_Bullshit()


    i += 1
    print(i)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        Camera.Stop_Code()
```

Question 1:
I consistently receive this within my console and I would like to get to rid of it for debugging later down the line.
`Corrupt JPEG data: 4 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd5`
Every time this pops up it is at a different marker, so I do not know how to not print that to the console.

Question 2:
After the code within the if statement: `if i % 10 == 0 and i != 0:` runs the code spits back this error.
`File "Nueral_Network_Creation.py", line 23, in Measurement_Bullshit self.cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']) ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

I understand that it is most likely that the code is not finding enough contours to be run properly or maybe it is something completely different. As always any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if `M['m00']` is 0, you have zero division (and hence the error). Possible solutions: test beforehand and handle the case appropriately (strongly recommented) or add a small epsilon to the denominator and ensure it's never exactly zero (likely a bad idea in your case)

Comment: Thank you for answering question 2. Do you have any suggestions for question 1?

Comment: Mildly unrelated note: OpenCV image layout is typically BGR rather than RGB, so this line: `self.buf4 = cv2.cvtColor(self.buf3, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)` should most likely be `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`.

Comment: I must've accidentally commented it out, but I actually converted it from BGR to RGB within the Img_mod function. Thank you thou, I'll fix that now